Do appstore pending payments expire?
I made an in-game top-up of $99USD in a game. It was a mistake, and since I didn’t have enough funds on my bank account it was automatically rejected. However, the game still gave me the currency I bought, and the payment showed as pending in the Apple appstore. I got the in game items, but I didn’t pay for them and Apple froze my account (couldn’t update or download apps). I contacted Apple customer support and they told me they can’t cancel the purchase since it’s pending, and told me to add another card, pay for the item and then ask for a reimbursement. I’m not going to do that since I know Apple doesn’t always provide reimbursement. I explained this to customer service and they implied that I should create a new apple ID and not use the one with the pending payment anymore
Do you know if these pending payments ever expire and automatically get cancelled? Considering I haven’t paid for it and I got the in game items one would think Apple would cancel the pending payment sooner or later. I contacted the game’s customer service as well and told me they can’t take the items I purchased unless Apple cancels the purchase beforehand. So we’re in kind of a standoff. Do you know what Apple does in this kind of situations?

I’ve never heard of them rejecting a refund request that was reasonable and yours is more than documented and reasonable. Are you sure you won’t follow Apple’s advice? How long between the original purchase and now has elapsed?
